# Accurate DateTime string format

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, formatdatetime

I have a `DateTime` variable that holds the following value: `5/11/2014 7:56:26 am`

I am currently using the following code to format this as a string: `uDate.ToString("s")`. Using this code, I get the following value: `2014-11-05T07:56:26`

I need this to be more accurate. The exact value I am wanting to get is in the following range of accuracy: `2014-11-05T07:56:26.4`

I have done some research at the following link: http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime

Here is what I have found:

> This profile does not specify how many digits may be used to represent
>   the decimal fraction of a second. An adopting standard that permits
>   fractions of a second must specify both the minimum number of digits
>   (a number greater than or equal to one) and the maximum number of
>   digits (the maximum may be stated to be "unlimited").

The value I am wanting to get is the value used on `Azure` when displaying a `DateTime` variable in a web service request.

How can I format my own `DateTime` strings so that they are the same format as the format used on `Azure`? Is there a specific format that `Azure` uses?

Basically, how can I format a `DateTime` string to be more accurate than the code: `uDate.ToString("s")`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the most "complete" information would be to use the "O" value, including fractions and also TimeZone (when available).

```
var myDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("o");
```

See also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article. Microsoft states that "complies with ISO 8601" and every .Net platform (also Azure) is able to read this string as DateTime, and also properly set the 'DateTimeKind' when available.

Comment: But this specifier has `..fffffff..` as a miliseconds part. I don't think OP wants this.

Comment: Actually if you want to be more accurate, you have to provide more information, including time fractions AND timezone, which also are standardized for webservices.

Comment: Thank you. The accuracy is a lot more accurate than the "s" format and is working as expected.

Answer (score 3):

[`"s"` standard format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Sortable) uses [`SortableDateTimePattern` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.sortabledatetimepattern%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) of your `CurrentCulture` and it doesn't includes miliseconds part.

This format specifier is always the same regardless the culture you use and it is `"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"` format.

You can just use [custom date and time format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) like;

```
uDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.f");
```